# Tell Node.js server to run a function by using javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http

I'm trying to send the command to execute a function in Node.js from an html Button and don't really know where to start.

So I'm currently working on a website that should be able to control my raspberry pi's GPIO pins and send commands to another Linux-Based Computer in the raspberry's network.

I already have the functions to do the above completed in javascript and it works perfectly fine when executed in Node.js. The only Problem is, that when directly implemented into an html, the code is not executed on the raspberry but in the browswer.
I now know I'll have to host a Node.js server on the Raspberry and send commands to that. But that exactly is my problem.

server.js :

```
function serverShutdown() {

    { some working code }

}
```

index.html :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="../scripts/client.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="ButtonClass">
            <button onclick="server_shutdown()">Herunterfahren</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

client.js :

```
function server_shutdown() {

    ? ? ?

}
```

Comment: Node.js is executed server side, so IMHO, inside `server_shutdown()` you could use an Ajax call to execute some server side script.

Comment: You don't need any JS on the client. A regular HTML form will do the job. (Or a link, but you shouldn't **do** things on a GET request). The complicated part is writing the HTTP server … and you haven't started that.

Comment: @Andrew I'm going to look for Ajax.. I've already heard of it but hadn't got time to get into it yet. Tanks for the Tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the http module in your server side app to handle an http request from a client to your server.

You could look at this link : https://nodejs.dev/the-nodejs-http-module

From the client side you should call an url that the server could handle. Or you need to create an event handler on the server side. 
More informations at : https://www.npmjs.com/package/events

Moreover your server should have module that exports the methods you need.

Comment: Hey, tbh I'm completely overwhelmed by the documentation on the http module. I might be able to get a server up but how do i declare what the http is going to do when recieving a specific signal?

Comment: Obviously you need to use the framework. expressjs.com